# Memory access in CUDA kernel functions (simple example)

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I am novice in GPU parallel computing and I'm trying to learn CUDA by looking at some examples in NVidia "CUDA by examples" book.

And I do not understand properly how thread access and change variables in such a simple example (dot product of two vectors).

The kernel function is defined as follows

```
__global__ void dot( float *a, float *b, float *c ) {    
  __shared__ float cache[threadsPerBlock];   
 int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;    
 int cacheIndex = threadIdx.x;
 float   temp = 0;

 while (tid < N) {
    temp += a[tid] * b[tid];
    tid += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
  }

    // set the cache values
  cache[cacheIndex] = temp;
```

I do not understand three things.

1. What is the sequence of execution of this function? Is there any sequence between threads? For example, the first are the thread from the first block, then threads from the second block come into play and so on (this is connected to the question why this is necessary to divide threads into blocks).
2. Do all threads have their own copy of the "temp" variable or not (if not, why is there no race condition?)
3. How is it operated? What exactly goes to the variable *temp* in the *while* loop? The array *cache* stores values of *temp* for different threads. How does the summation go on? It seems that *temp* already contains all sums necessary for dot product because variable *tid* goes from 0 to N-1 in the *while* loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the code you provide is incomplete, here are some clarifications about what you are asking :

1. The kernel code will be executed by all the threads in all the blocks. The way to "split the jobs" is to make threads work only on one or a few elements.
   For instance, if you have to treat 100 integers with a specific algorithm, you probably want 100 threads to treat 1 element each.
   In CUDA the amount of blocks and threads is defined at the kernel launch on host side :

`myKernel<<<grid, threads>>>(...);`

Where **grids** and **threads** are ***dim3***, which define the size on three dimensions.

There is no specific order in the execution of threads and blocks. As you can read there :
http://mc.stanford.edu/cgi-bin/images/3/34/Darve_cme343_cuda_3.pdf
On page 6 : "No specific order in which blocks are dispatched and executed".

2. Since the **temp** variable is defined in the kernel in no specific way, it is not distributed and each thread will have this value stored in a register.

This is equivalent of what is done on CPU side. So yes, this means each threads has its own "temp" variable.

3. The **temp** variable is updated in each iteration of the loop, using access to device arrays.

Again, this is equivalent of what is done on CPU side.

I think you should probably check if you are used enough to C/C++ programming on CPU side before going further into GPU programming. Meaning no offense, it seems you have a lack in several main topics.
Since CUDA allows you to drive your GPU with C code, the difficulty is not in the syntax, but in the specificities of the hardware.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I guess my question was maybe misleading, because you're answer is not I asked about unfortunately. I meant the following: 1) is there any sequence of between threads? for example, the first are the thread from the first block, then threads from the second block come into play and so on (this is connected to the question why this is necessary to divide threads into blocks); 2) do all threads have their own copy of the "temp" variable or not (if not, why is there no race condition?);

Comment: See my updated answer. No specific order in threads execution within a block, nor between blocks. And yes, each thread stores its temp value, do you understand what are the on-chip registers ?

Comment: thank you very much for edited answer. I think I understand what is on-chip register (though I can not tell exact definition). So, there is no race condition for "temp" variable because it is not shared, and each thread works with its own copy of "thread" variable, right?

Comment: I don't call it a "copy" as it could imply misunderstanding, but as I wrote in my edited answer, yes, each thread has it own "temp" variable.
If my answer helped please consider accepting it to help moderators who have to iterate on unanswered questions ;)